# Win Task Scheduler: Start A Task Based on Other Multiple Task Successes

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

Based on [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davethompson/archive/2011/10/25/running-a-scheduled-task-after-another.aspx) work

I want to extend the custom XPath given below for the following case: I have tasks. A, B, C, and D.  A, B, and C are all set to run at 7am. Sometimes the action fails, and when it does, the task restarts the application until it succeeds.  When A, B, and C are done, I want D to trigger.   What is the XPATH that I would use **to make D trigger**?

Query from article:

```
<QueryList>
   <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
      <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">*[EventData
[@Name='TaskSuccessEvent'][Data[@Name='TaskName']='\Ping']]</Select>
   </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Comment: I have the XPATH to run A, B, C until application is success. I  also know how to do it if I wanted to say trigger a task E after a single task is finishes (like in the article). I just need to know how to trigger after multiple successes!  THANKS!

Comment: You can always ask the author directly right in the comments section on the webpage. He'll have a better answer than most of us.

Comment: Not a bad idea, just an older article.

Comment: Here is the same question asked on TechNet.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/14841f8f-0e5a-4176-b789-28ac62db6c90/task-scheduler-trigger-event-on-multiple-different-previous-events-success?forum=winserverManagement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting in various places online, it is of popular belief that Windows Task Manager can not handle such a request.

---

Personally, I am using this for an ETL system. After looking at the Microsoft Build session for Data Factory, I believe this may be the right tool for me. Other enterprise task tools exist for different applications that also have this functionality.